# c# паттерн MVP управление формами через MainView

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

при отображение формы с помощью главной формы MainView не могу отобразить данные правильно, а так же не могу самостоятельно настроить ширину Datagridview, выдает исключение, помогите пожалуйста разобраться как управлять формами с помощью главной формы по паттерну MVP, и отображать данные правильно.
форма должна выглядит так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
выглядит так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ниже выложил код и изображение ошибки

```
namespace Telecom_Sklad_MVP.Views
{
    public partial class MainView : Form, IMainView
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btn_Product.Click += delegate { ShowProductView?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); };
        }
        
        public event EventHandler ShowProductView;

        private void MainView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public DataGridView DVG()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

код MainPresenter

```
namespace Telecom_Sklad_MVP.Preseneters
{
    public  class MainPresenter
    {
        private IMainView mainView;
        private readonly string mysqlConnectionString;
    
        public MainPresenter(IMainView mainView, string mysqlConnectionString)
        {
            this.mainView = mainView;
            this.mysqlConnectionString = mysqlConnectionString;
            this.mainView.ShowProductView += ShowProductView;
        }

        private void ShowProductView(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IProductView view = ProductView.GetInstance((MainView)mainView);
            IProductRepository repository = new ProductRepository(mysqlConnectionString);
            new ProductPresenter(view, repository);
        }
    }
}
```

главный интерфейс

```
namespace Telecom_Sklad_MVP.Views
{
    public interface IMainView
    {
        event EventHandler ShowProductView;
        DataGridView DVG();
    }
}
```

```
    namespace Telecom_Sklad_MVP.Views
{
    public partial class ProductView : Form, IProductView
    {
        private string message;
        private bool isSuccessful;
        private bool isEdit;
        public ProductView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AssociateAndRaiseViewEvents();
         
        }

        public string ProductId
        {
            get { return txt_Id.Text; }
            set { txt_Id.Text = value; }
        }
        public string ProducttName
        {
            get { return txt_productName.Text; }
            set { txt_productName.Text = value; }
        }
        public string ProductQty
        {
            get { return txt_qty.Text; }
            set { txt_qty.Text = value; }
        }
        public string ProductPrice
        {
            get { return txt_price.Text; }
            set { txt_price.Text = value; }
        }
        public string ProductTotal
        {
            get { return txt_total.Text; }
            set { txt_total.Text = value; }
        }
        public string ProductNote
        {
            get { return txt_note.Text; }
            set { txt_note.Text = value; }
        }
        public string ProductDate
        {
            get { return dateTimePicker1.Text; }
            set { dateTimePicker1.Text = value; }
        }
        public string CategoryId
        {
            get { return labelIdCategory.Text; }
            set { labelIdCategory.Text = value; }
        }
        public string CompanyId
        {
            get { return comboBox_Company.Text; }
            set { comboBox_Company.Text = value; }
        }
        public string UnitId
        {
            get { return comboBox_unit.Text; }
            set { comboBox_unit.Text = value; }
        }

        public bool IsEdit
        {
            get { return isEdit; }
            set { isEdit = value; }
        }
        public bool IsSuccessful
        {
            get { return isSuccessful; }
            set { isSuccessful = value; }
        }
        public string Message
        {
            get { return message; }
            set { message = value; }
        }

        public string ComboboxCategoryId
        {
            get { return comboBox_Category.Text; }
            set { comboBox_Category.Text = value; }
        }
        public string ComboboxCategoryName
        {
            get { return comboBox_Category.Text; }
            set { comboBox_Category.Text = value; }
        }

        public event EventHandler AddNewEvent;
        public event EventHandler EditEvent;
        public event EventHandler DeleteEvent;
        public event EventHandler SaveEvent;


        public void SetProductListBindingSource(BindingSource productList)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = productList;
  
        }
        private void AssociateAndRaiseViewEvents() // вызов событий или еще что-то
        {
          
           
            // Add new 
            btn_Add.Click += delegate
            {
                AddNewEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
              
            };
            // Edit
            btn_Edit.Click += delegate
            {
                EditEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
              
            };
            // Save
            btn_Add.Click += delegate
            {
                SaveEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                if (isSuccessful)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Message);
                }
            };
           
            // Delete
            btn_delete.Click += delegate
            {
                var result = MessageBox.Show("Вы хотите удалить выделенную строку?", "Warning",
                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    DeleteEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    MessageBox.Show(Message);
                }
            };
           
          //  DVGStyle();
        }
        private void ProductView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox_Category.DisplayMember = "name";
            comboBox_Category.ValueMember = "id";
            comboBox_Category.Text = "Select Category";
            comboBox_Company.DisplayMember = "name";
            comboBox_Company.ValueMember = "id";
            comboBox_Company.Text = "Select Company";
            comboBox_unit.DisplayMember = "name";
            comboBox_unit.ValueMember = "id";
            comboBox_unit.Text = "Select Unit";
            //  DVGStyle();
            DVGStyle();
        }
      public  void DVGStyle()
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 150;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 60;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 70;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 80;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 80;
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width = 120;
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].Width = 120;
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].Width = 120;
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].Width = 120;
        }

        void IProductView.ShowDialog()
        {
            comboBox_Category.DisplayMember = "name";
            comboBox_Category.ValueMember = "id";
            comboBox_Category.Text = "Saýla";
        }

        private static ProductView instance;
        public static ProductView GetInstance(Form parentContainer)
        {
            if (instance == null || instance.IsDisposed)
            {
                instance = new ProductView
                {
                    MdiParent = parentContainer,
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                };
            }
            else
            {
                if (instance.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                    instance.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                instance.BringToFront();

            }
            return instance;
        }
        public void SetCategoryListBindingSource(BindingSource categoryList)
        {
            comboBox_Category.DataSource = categoryList;
        }

        public void SetCompanyListBindingSource(BindingSource companyList)
        {
            comboBox_Company.DataSource = companyList;
        }

        public void SetUnitListBindingSource(BindingSource unitList)
        {
            comboBox_unit.DataSource = unitList;

        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Id.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txt_productName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txt_qty.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            comboBox_unit.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txt_price.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            txt_total.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            comboBox_Category.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            comboBox_Company.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            txt_note.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();

        }
        private void Txt_qty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txt_qty.Text == "")
                {
                    txt_total.Clear();
                }
                else if (txt_productName.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please , Enter Product Name ", "Try Again", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txt_productName.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    double tprice;
                    tprice = double.Parse(txt_price.Text) * double.Parse(txt_qty.Text);
                    txt_total.Text = tprice.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        private void ComboBox_Category_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelIdCategory.Text = comboBox_Category.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
        private void ComboBox_unit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void SetUnitListBindingSource(BindingSource unitList, ComboBox unit)
        {
            comboBox_unit.DataSource = unitList;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `выдает исключение` какое именно - надо догадаться? В какой строке? Текст исключения вставьте текстом в вопрос и укажите строку кода, где оно возникает.

Comment: По поводу задания ширины контролов: [Position and layout of controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout?view=netdesktop-6.0). Также смотрите [Automatic scaling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/forms/autoscale?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Кстати да, пора бы уже `FlowLayoutPanel` и `TableLayoutPanel` освоить, код вы вроде не вчера начали писать.

Comment: @aepot, простите , пишет индекс за пределами диапазона

Comment: @aepot, выложил код отображение формы и общую картину, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Не вижу ничего того, о чем вы говорите, обновите страницу

Comment: @aepot, исправил

Comment: при загрузке формы все отображается грамотно , но если после загрузки формы еще раз нажать на кнопку Product  главной форме , отображается то, что на изображение

Comment: `изображение ошибки` - где? укажите текст ошибки и конкретную строку кода, где это исключение возникает. Я не буду больше вас допрашивать, сами добавьте все необходимые детали. В текущем виде нка вопрос ответить невозможно.

Comment: @aepot, исключение возникал из за того, что  самой форме указал не существующий столбец  datagridview,  а так не могу управлять формами через MainPresenter( название столбцов , ширина и .т.д ) еще при переходе в другую форму  данные меняется, как видно на фотографии выше